# Set table page size pagination dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set custom page sizes options for my table, I have total rows length and I am trying to get calculated values so if I have `32` rows it will show `10, 20, 30` on my dropdown but when total length is over `100`, the result will be `10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100`.

I'd appreciate any suggestions and guidelines to achieve this, thanks.


[image]

```
rows length , expected output 

7 => [10]
32 => [10, 20, 30]
50 => [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
104 => [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100]
245 => [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100, 200]
```

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: So, is your intention here to go up by 10s up until 50, then go up by 50s up until 100, then go up by 100s thereafter?

Comment: @costaparas yes. 10s until 50, 50s until 100, ..

Comment: @Mitya sorry, I've only tried basic loops and methods that's why I didnt post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getArrayWithDivisor = (num, div) => {
  return Array(Math.floor(num / div))
    .fill(undefined)
    .map((el, i) => (i + 1) * div);
};

getInitDiv = (num, x = 10) => {
  return num < x ? x : getInitDiv(num, x * 10);
};

_getDropDownOptionsFromRows = (num, initDiv) =>
  initDiv >= 10
    ? _getDropDownOptionsFromRows(
        initDiv / 2 > num ? num : initDiv / 2,
        initDiv / 10
      ).concat(getArrayWithDivisor(num, initDiv))
    : [];

getDropDownOptionsFromRows = (num) =>
  _getDropDownOptionsFromRows(num, getInitDiv(num));
```

Comment: Wait a sec, I will add an even more general version for you to be able to handle thousands, millions etc.